# Transient hostname was changed in a server

Tags: linux, centos, router, hostname

In one of our production server automatically set `transient` hostname.
`hostnamectl status`  shows

```
   Static hostname: abc11.example.com
Transient hostname: I
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: xxxxxx
           Boot ID: xxxxxx
    Virtualization: microsoft
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Server was not rebooted recently (up for 439 days)

In message logs:

```
Sep  6 12:33:42 abc11 dbus[6119]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Sep  6 12:33:43 abc11 dbus[6119]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep  6 13:15:50 abc11 dbus[6119]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
Sep  6 13:15:50 abc11 dbus[6119]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Sep  6 13:53:41 abc11 dbus[6119]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service'
```

Could this be an issue related to network router as described [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=202704)? Or any other issue such as attack?

This server deployed in client's data centre.